# How do I know what file was opened when someone uses my program with "Open With"?(C#)

Tags: c#, windows, file

I wrote a C# program for converting and re-sizing images. If someone opens a bitmap with my program with "Open With...", how do I "handle" that event and figure out which file they just opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locate your `Main()` method

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ...
}
```

the `args` gets all the command line parameters and the file name should be in there.

Answer (score 4):

Use [System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) or String args[] parameter passed to your Main method. The name of the file that is being opened will be there.